Does new-relic triggers the apis in the service by itself when iast is enabled or it intercepts the api req which are already triggered by someone?
How does new-relic iast work exactly? does it trigger all the apis present in our service by itself or we have to hit the apis so that it can intercept and check the vulnerabilities?
